# Php mailer cant send mail on webmail

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, webmail

iam not receiving any mail on my webmail but if i put gmail credentials i receive mail

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer();  

// Set up SMTP  

$mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
$mail->Host = "mail.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                      // 1 = errors and messages
                                      // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
$mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';

// Authentication  
$mail->Username   = "admin@example.com"; // Your full  address
$mail->Password   = "password"; // Your  password

// Compose
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
$mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

// Send To  
$mail->AddAddress("recipientemail@gmail.com", "Recipient Name"); // Where to send it - Recipient
$result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
$message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
unset($mail);
```

i have tried 10 times but on gmail iam recieving mail but not on webmail

Answer (score 0):

You're using `SMTPSecure = "ssl"` with `Port = 587`. That won't work, which you would know if you'd bothered to base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) instead of some broken, obsolete thing you found elsewhere.

At the very least you should use `SMTPSecure = "tls"` with `Port = 587`, and follow that up by [reading the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

Comment: buddy by mistake that happened i have already tried using 465 port

Comment: Then don't post code that you know is wrong. It just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: but not on my domain mail

Comment: So enable debug output and see what it's doing

Comment: it is not showing any error just showing the series of 2xx so there isn't any error but i am not recieving any mail but if u want i can post it for u

Comment: You do need to put in *some* effort you know - I really can't read the docs for you! Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` and show the output, exactly like the docs I already pointed you at say.